# Failed to start Glue Notebook server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to create a Glue Studio job using Jupyter Notebook option.
But I am getting this error:

```
Role arn:aws:iam::role/AWSGlueServiceNotebookRoleDefault should be given assume role permissions for Glue Service. (Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Proxy: null)
```

I have attached following policies to Glue Role

```
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSGlueServiceRole
AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole
AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess
```